When iOS 17 sends UDP, System Net Sockets SocketException (65): Norout to host
I am using Maui and NET 8 in Visual Studio 2022, And implement UDP and TCP messages sent on iOS 17. There is an issue with UDP not being able to send messages and displaying error messages: System NET Sockets SocketException (65): No route to host, Sent peer-to-peer information, not multicast,but everything is normal on Windows and Android, with the same WiFi assigned IP address and port. The code is as follows:
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("The IP address of WiFi
"), 8989);
tcpListener.Start();

IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("WiFi router address
"), 57788);
udpClient.Send(requestBytes, requestBytes.Length, remoteEP);

await Task.Delay(20);
TcpClient udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
byte[] responseBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEP);

The code is in udpClient.Send(), error System Net Sockets SocketException (65): Norout to host. Please provide some suggestions. Thank you
I tried to configure the following permissions in info.plist:
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the local network to communicate with devices.</string>

Trying is useless.
I tried using a temporary distribution package for installation, but it didn't solve the problem. Even using a hot restart doesn't work. I used software to ping the WiFi router address on my iOS 17 phone and it was successful.Please give me some suggestions.

Does this problem only occur in iOS17? Can message be sent normally in iOS16?

In fact, when using TCP and UDP peer-to-peer communication on iOS, it is necessary to confirm whether the application has enabled the "wireless data" permission. The steps are: Settings ->Your application ->Select wireless LAN and cellular network
